# Weighing options for personal HSM?

Tags: password-management, key-management, fips, yubikey, hsm

I'm trying to weigh my options for a personal HSM. I wish to store both passwords and private PGP keys. I've been doing my research but I'm not a security expert and am feeling slightly overwhelmed; please educate me.

1. [This project](https://www.palkeo.com/sys/perfect-password-manager.html) uses Yubikey 4 with [passwordstore](https://www.passwordstore.org/). Yubikey seems trusted by consumers despite having closed source firmware, but I'm still skeptical since I cannot find any audits of (or known vulnerabilities in) the firmware. I do like the touch-based auth feature.
2. [Nitrokey](https://shop.nitrokey.com/shop) is completely open source unlike Yubikey 4, but more expensive, and I wonder if it would be significantly more secure to have [FIPS 140-2](https://www.corsec.com/fips-140-2/) validation (tamper-proof is attractive.)
3. Putting a [passwordstore](https://www.passwordstore.org/) and private PGP keys on a FIPS 140-2 validated USB drive would probably be the easiest to back up (given a second encrypted drive), but this isn't an HSM at all.
4. Perhaps [GNUK](http://www.fsij.org/doc-gnuk/) could be useful, but I don't want to build a HSM from scratch.

Finally, [this page](https://www.devever.net/~hl/smartcards) suggests Yubikey/Nitrokey might not be as secure as they advertise.

Having read my concerns, are any of these options flawed, and is anyone of them clearly optimal / 'most secure'? Feel free to suggest alternative ideas.

Comment: I'd go with a smart card with a keypad on it

Comment: Can you elaborate, perhaps in an answer? I don't fully understand why a smart card would be more secure than some of the above options.

Comment: A smart card is essentially a personal HSM. Not more secure necessarily but inexpensive and readily available. Though a pin pad can help w security